# how to add an item to a list in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to add an item to the list in React.js. Here is my code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/JEG6o4JCBIQWAt2A4S3r?p=preview

I want to add text value of the input field to the list when user clicks on add button. In my demo  I have  `add button`and upon click I want to add the item to the list.
Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong ?

```
Code:

const { createStore, bindActionCreators, applyMiddleware,combineReducers } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const thunk = window.ReduxThunk.default;


const first_redux =function(state ='' ,action){
  switch (action.type){
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
     return action.payload
    default :
    return state

  }
}

const actions ={
 addItem :function(item){
  return {
    type :"ADD_ITEM",
    payload :item
  } 
 }  

}
var combindReducer = combineReducers({
  item:first_redux
})

const store = createStore(combindReducer);

class First extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names :[],
      username :''
    }
   this.changeEv =this.changeEv.bind(this);
   this.addName =this.addName.bind(this);
  }
  changeEv(e){
    this.setState({
      username : e.target.value
    })
  }
  addName(){
   // this.state.names.push(this.state.username);
    console.log(this.state);
    this.props.add(this.state.username)
  }

  render() {
    const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
    var listItems = this.state.names.map(function(d, idx){
      return (<li key={idx}>{d.name}</li>)
    })
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="text" onChange ={this.changeEv}/>
      <button onClick={this.addName}>add</button>
      {listItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

function mapStateToProps(state){
  console.log('=================');
  console.log(state);
  return {
       names: state.item,

  };
    console.log(this.state);

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    add:bindActionCreators(actions.addItem,dispatch)
  }
}
const Appcontainer =connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(First)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store ={store}>
    <Appcontainer/>
    </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple changes in your code, in this case when you are using redux, the store is outside of the component and the mapDispatchToProps is mapping the global state with component's props.

// Code goes here

```
const { createStore, bindActionCreators, applyMiddleware,combineReducers } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const thunk = window.ReduxThunk.default;

const initialState = []

const first_redux =function(state = initialState ,action){
  switch (action.type){
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
     let newState = action.payload;
     return [...state,newState];
    default :
    return state

  }
}

const actions ={
 addItem :function(item){
  return {
    type :"ADD_ITEM",
    payload :item
  } 
 }  

}
var combindReducer = combineReducers({
  item:first_redux
})

const store = createStore(combindReducer);

class First extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username :''
    }
   this.changeEv =this.changeEv.bind(this);
   this.addName =this.addName.bind(this);
  }
  changeEv(e){
    this.setState({
      username : e.target.value
    })
  }
  addName(){
   // this.state.names.push(this.state.username);
    console.log(this.state);
    this.props.add(this.state.username)
  }

  render() {
    const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
    var listItems = this.props.names.map(function(d, idx){
      return (<li key={idx}>{d}</li>)
    })
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="text" onChange ={this.changeEv}/>
      <button onClick={this.addName}>add</button>
      {listItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

function mapStateToProps(state){
  console.log('=================');
  console.log(state);
  return {
       names: state.item,

  };
    console.log(this.state);

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    add:bindActionCreators(actions.addItem,dispatch)
  }
}
const Appcontainer =connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(First)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store ={store}>
    <Appcontainer/>
    </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/e6oJXempwk0e5GciOSSB?p=previewp

Answer (score 0):

What you return in your reducer is basically the state of your application, but right now you're just returning your payload, thus your state, in this case, is just a single item. What you want though, is for your state to be a list of items, thus your state should create an array, not just return the payload. Note the state in the reducer should be immutable, so we cannot simple push the new payload on to the last state.

Here's an example of how you could implement  this:

```
const first_redux = function(state = [] ,action){
  switch (action.type){
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return [
        ...state,
        action.payload
      ];
    default :
      return state
  }
}

var combindReducer = combineReducers({
  items: first_redux
})

function mapStateToProps(state){
  console.log('=================');
  console.log(state);
  return {
    names: state.items,
  };
}
```